# Is there any way to share an Image file to MS teams channel using python

Tags: python, automation, microsoft-teams, onedrive, azure-automation

I want to share some images (Local or stored in one drive, no issue) as a file attachment to MS Teams channel (not chat) using python.
I've already tried using Requests module and Webhooks to send Images (using base64 encoding and links), but they are the tiny images which can't be opened. I've also tried the Azure bot but it's only useful if we want to sent the image file to the chat.
If you do know, Can you share some sample working code (instead of sharing [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-files#using-the-microsoft-graph-apis)) here.

Comment: Can you please check on this sample once: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/15.handling-attachments

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Sure, I'll confirm, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is not proper chance to send images using python in teams. One of the previous researchers worked on this. As you are not focusing on bot and directly need to share the image using python. There is no procedure to accomplish the task.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/post-image-to-teams-channel-from-local-path-using-python/m-p/2484798